# OpenVPN options for internal instance name resolver on GCE

Tags: openvpn, internal-dns, google-compute-engine

What option should be set under OpenVPN for config across Google Compute Engine to allow connected client to resolve/ping by instance name and resolve to its ip same way as it can be done when on any instance on GCE?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your server.conf :

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
```

You will not be able to ping the instance by name. The instance name is used in conjunction with gcloud commands. The workaround is to add the IPs as names in /etc/resolv.conf

Also, you may want to add `push "dhcp-option DNS 169.254.169.254"`

Let me know how this works for you !